# Building a Google Maps Directions URL with waypoints (that aren't stops)

Tags: google-maps, mobile, directions

I want to go from a place to another using a Google Maps Directions URL in the Google Maps Mobile App. This is from Lisboa to Porto, in Portugal :)

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/38.759741,-9.153736/41.1454953,-8.6108788/

As you can see, I only gave the origin and destination coordinates and it works.

In my final solution I would like to ask the Google Maps App for the same route, but forcing it to pass through a location (39.657293,-8.827500). This is not a stop so I I cannot treat it as a waypoint.

I saw several options in other posts but none is working for me.

Any thoughts?

Than you very much for you help

Comment: Why do you think adding the waypoint to the URL doesn't work? (https://www.google.com/maps/dir/38.759741,-9.153736/39.657293,-8.827500/41.1454953,-8.6108788)

Comment: @geocodezip because when the route is navigated on the mobile, the Google Maps App (in navigation mode) treats the point as a stop which is not true. I don't want to give the user the false expectation that he arrived to the destination.

Comment: There is no mention of mobile in your question.  That might be good to add.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @geocodezip. Add it already :)